# Reference request: Numerical techniques, Monte-Carlo (MC), Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG), Dynamical Mean-Field Theory (DMFT)

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, algorithms

I am an undergraduate student and my previous learning in physics is more on theory instead of numerics. I would be very grateful if you can point me to good **introductory** lecture notes/lecture videos on these numerical techniques and how they are employed in physics

**(it would be the best if the notes/videos you introduced are short, in a sense that probably a grad student can finish reading it within one week)**:

Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG), Monte Carlo simulation,  Dynamical Mean-Field Theory (DMFT)

Edit: Since there are comments saying that these are quite distinct topics and are worth separate questions. I would be grateful if you can offer suggestions on possible references on any of the topics listed here

Comment: It would be much better to post a separate question for each of the topics. These are rather different methods.

Comment: I sincerely believe these methods are not introductory. I doubt anyone could get a good understanding of any one of them within a week.
Technically, Martin, "Interacting Electrons" is a textbook that covers QMC and DMFT, but it is not an introductory text by any means. So unfortunately, your requirements are too stringent.